# How do you join all models that reference a model into one table in Django?

Tags: python, django, join, django-models

I have multiple Django models that reference a model using foreign keys as such:

```
class LocationHistory(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(WorldGrid)
    ...

class UserSynthVals(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(WorldGrid)
    ...

class RegionalVictoryRate(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(WorldGrid)
    ...
```

Where WorldGrid is just:

```
class WorldGrid(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

Now, I am able to get all the models that reference WorldGrid (abstractly for reusability) with:

```
models_that_reference = [i.model for i in get_model('appname',model_name)._meta.get_all_related_objects()]
```

And at that point I can loop through them getting their model.objects.all().values(), but I cannot find a way to join those separate lists of objects into one that I could then output to a table.

I would rather do something more along the lines of django's expected use (like what select_related() does) and keep this abstract.

Any help solving this problem would be appreciated, or a new direction to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a pretty good way of doing this, and the select_related was indeed the key. Once I have a list of the referencing models, I can do:

```
fields_that_reference = [[m._meta.object_name.lower()+'__'+f.name for f in m._meta.fields if not isinstance(f,related.ForeignKey) ] for m in models_that_reference]

for i in fields_that_reference:
    fields +=i
```

To get all of the fields that I am trying to see at once, and then:

```
all_objects = get_model('appname',model_name).objects.select_related().values(*fields)
```

To get them all into one giant list. If your models are historic (with datetime fields), or have circular foreignkeys, you will probably need to prune this result a little more before displaying it, but this gets everything together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with filters. You want to join WorldGrid to its related models and filter out where there isn't a join.

```
WorldGrid.objects.filter( regionalvictoryrate_region__isnull=False,
                      usersynthvals_region__isnull=False,
                      locationhistory_region__isnull=False )
```

See the notes here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I tried this (with only usersynthvals) and recieved AttributeError: type object 'UserSynthVals' has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Strange sorry i can't help you more here @creatorjames. I do tihnk filters are the way to go if you want to use models. Another option is to jump over the models totally and query you data directly using SQL

Comment: apologies, that seems to have been the wrong error. I was able to make your answer work by adding another underscore before region, but I believe that all this does is get the WorldGrids where there is a usersynth... that refernces it. What I want is all of those things that refernce it, in the same table

Comment: It's a foreign key of word grid for what you want do the same as above but you'll have to  model region as foreign key relationship in world grids (spinning the model around) . I think filtering is the key for django joins so please vote up and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have modified and play with the get_deleted_objects function from the admin, in django.contrib.admin.util to do just that, return all the related objects and display them or manipulate them in some form. It could be a good start to accomplish what you want.